# Error message DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=MCX28303.BANKACCOUNTS, DRIVER=4.26.14

Tags: sql, db2

I am populating data into db2 from my local machine (BankAccounts.sql) while executing the file I'm getting the below error Error message DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=MCX28303.BANKACCOUNTS, DRIVER=4.26.14

Stuck don't know what to do next?

Comment: It means where is a mistake in your query. But your question does not show the query so we cannot help!   Learn how to ask a good question. The object `MCX28303.BANKACCOUNTS` does not exist.

Comment: In Db2 the names of objects are case sensitive, so when the real object name is BankAccounts then you must use double-quotes "BankAccounts" (for example). The same for the schema name, use quotes if mixed case, otherwise Db2 will assume the object name is all upper case.

Comment: Please, edit your question with the exact  `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how DB2 tells you what happened.

In this case the database tells you the code "-204" and the message "MCX28303.BANKACCOUNTS".

The code you have to look up here: ( Which Db2 are you using? this one is for z/OS version 12)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n204.html

And the message points to your mistake.
Finally the IBM-documentation often gives you advice what to do (see "Programmer response").

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is an issue with schema. As you are using MCX28303 as schema you can try to set schema first like
**set schema = MCX28303;**
and after that you can run your query without schema.
I tried this way and it's working for me.